# find column average and display results

Tags: r

my dataframe consists of 200 variables names(columns) and I want to find the average of each column which is easy with functions(eg. colMeans) but they give me a vector.
How I can display the results in a dataframe with the names of the variables in the first column and the mean of each variable in a second column in order to filter them?

Comment: ``data.frame(mean = colMeans(mtcars), name = colnames(mtcars))``

Comment: for some reason the code didn't help me. I get an '' Error in data.frame(., mean = colMeans(x = .), name = colnames(x = .)) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 133, 202  ''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
data.frame(mean = colMeans(iris[1:4])) %>% tibble::rownames_to_column("Col")

           Col     mean
1 Sepal.Length 5.843333
2  Sepal.Width 3.057333
3 Petal.Length 3.758000
4  Petal.Width 1.199333
```